# node js await does not seem to wait

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, scope

I am making a request to a mySQL Database and want to work with the returned results. I have the async function

```
async function doQuery(query) {
  try {
    console.log('0. connection start');
    var connection = MySQL.createConnection({  
      host: "xxxxxxxx",
      user: "yyyyyyyy",
      password: "zzzzzzzz"
    });

    console.log('1. Connection set up. Connecting...');
    var queryResults;
    await connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log("2. Connected!");
      connection.query(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        queryResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log("3. " + util.inspect(result, {depth: 4}));
        console.log("3.5 " + util.inspect(queryResults, {depth: 4}));
        connection.end();
      });
    })

    console.log ("results before return:" + JSON.stringify(queryResults));
    return queryResults;
  }
  catch (err){
    console.log("async err: " + err);
  }
}
```

The function is then called from another function:

```
function handle async(handlerInput) {
  console.log("ExecuteDBSearchHandler");

  var query = buildQuery(handlerInput);
  try{
    var resultsPromise = doQuery(query)
      .then(results => {
        console.log("4. final results: " + results);
        const count = results.length;
        var speechText = 'Abfrage Erfolgreich, es gab ' + count + " Ergebnisse.";
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .withSimpleCard('Abfrage Erfolgreich', speechText)
          .withShouldEndSession(false)
          .getResponse();
      })
  }
  catch (err){
    console.log("error:" + err);
  }
}
```

This code is to be used in a nodejs Alexa skill. When the function runs, I would expect the outputs in the log to be ordered ascending. The output I consistently get is 0, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3.5. The .then part is executed before the actual connection is established and the database queried.

Instead of the .then, I tried a simple await before, making the line

```
var results = await doQuery(query);
```

This lead to the exact same result. I am at a loss as to why await is infact not waiting. As a sidenote: While inside the block

```
connection.query(query, function (err, result) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  queryResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
  console.log("3. " + util.inspect(result, {depth: 4}));
  console.log("3.5 " + util.inspect(queryResults, {depth: 4}));
  connection.end();
});
```

queryResults shows results (in the debug log step 3.5). In the line

```
console.log ("results before return:" + JSON.stringify(queryResults));
```

it returns undefined. I tried so many things to get the results to the function scope of doQuery, but I can't seem to achieve that. Does the await fail due to this? And how can I fix it? I have read upwards of a dozen articles and docs about async/await and promises, yet I can't figure this out.

Comment: To use `await` on the function it should return `Promise`.

Comment: Which **exact** MySQL node library are you using?  I suspect that `connection.connect` returns a Promise inately.

Comment: I am using mysql/sqljs, and as far as I know it only uses callbacks, I might be wrong about that, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your callback function in [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to make use of `await` keyword

For example:

```
async function dbQuery(query) {
    try {
        const connection = MySQL.createConnection({  
            host: "xxxxxxxx",
            user: "yyyyyyyy",
            password: "zzzzzzzz"
        });

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            connection.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) reject(err);

                connection.query(query, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) reject(err);
                    connection.end();
                    resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
                });
            });
        });
    } catch {
        console.error("async err: " + err);
    }
}
```

The one can also use [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to wrap `callback` in `promise`

Comment: This works like a charm! I tried so many things before, including util.promisify, but it broke the mySQL lib, so I must have used it incorrectly. This also solves the scope problem, since the result is returned. You made my day!